# "#" sign cannot be in csproj/sln pathname when debugging Razor class library in VS2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, iis-express

During learning the Razor class libraries (RCL) features I have found very strange error, which took me hours to determine. I cannot have `#` sign in the pathname, when trying to debug the project.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Clone repository [git@github.com:zoka-cz/CSharpDirNameProblem.git](https://github.com/zoka-cz/CSharpDirNameProblem) into any directory you want (iteration 1 - ensure `#` is not anywhere in the pathname like `c:\tmp\CSharpDirNameProblem\` | iteration 2 - ensure the `#` is in the directory name e.g. `c:\tmp\C#\CSharpDirNameProblem\`)
2. Open solution `src\CSharpDirNameProblem.sln` (I have VS2017, not sure about other versions)
3. Set `WebApplication1` as startup project and run.
4. In browser opened click `About` page and observe different results.
5. Go to second iteration from 1st point, otherwise finished.

The mentioned repository is minimal setup to reproduce the issue. Firstly it was created RCL project with few razor views. Then the `WebApplication` (MVC web application) project was created, the RCL added as reference, the `About` page was changed to test RCL project views. Very simple.
But, when there is `#` sign in the path of my project, then it fails to find the views from RCL. The webapplication works, but it does not find the RCL views. You may imagine the hours I have spent finding the problem. Now I know that I cannot have `#` in the name, but I would like to know why, and if it is possible to work around this problem (lot of my project resides in my `...Projects\C#` directory).

Has anyone the idea what causes the issue? Is it IIS Express? Is it Visual studio? Is it problem of the AspNetCore? Can I fix it alone somehow? May I find the source of problem by myself? Or maybe report it somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your scenario. That said, the `#` symbol is an identifier in URLs that indicates a `Fragment`. See this wiki for and explanation (also note it's using a # in the URL) ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax

Comment: The problem is, that when I create RCL project in location on my drive with `#` in pathname, it is not usable during the debugging - the WebApplication referencing that RCL says that view from RCL was not found. I'm not sure, that it has something with URL (but thats what I wanna find out)

Comment: When you debug does the `#` show in the URL that's displayed in the browser? If so then the browser is interpreting the `#` as a fragment identifier and everything after the fragment is being seen incorrectly as it's not a fragment but is in fact part of your URL.

Comment: No. The address is `http://localhost:xxx/About` for both cases, but it doesn't matter at all. Did you try my steps to reproduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the issue is legit, and I was able to reproduce it using Visual Studio 2019, and the .net core 3.0.100.

I raised a [bug report](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/17192) on the [AspNetCore](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore) repo(referencing your question here) since it doesn't look like something we can come up with a workaround to.

The good news is that it's already a well-known [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14501), and it's being addressed. The not so good news is that it won't be fixed until the *the next major release*.

Comment: Thanks @SamTheDev for your excessive effort. Althought I found the problem by myself (that the special char may not be in the path) I wanted to know the reason behind the problem - you definitely earn the bounty offered by doing more than I even expected.